# How to hide Archive/Unarchive and delete buttons based on groups from Action dropdown in CRM

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-13

How to hide the Archive, Unarchive and Delete buttons from action menu in CRM based on security groups in odoo13?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. To hide the delete option :
   for that specific security group remove the unlink permission from that group in the `ir.model.access.csv` of your module
2. To hide the Archive/Unarchive options : include a new js file to the web.assets_backend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="test_modulo_assets_backend" name="test modulo assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/test_modulo/static/src/js/basic_view.js"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

and in that js file put your logic :

```
odoo.define('test_modulo.BasicView', function (require) {
"use strict";

var session = require('web.session');
var BasicView = require('web.BasicView');
BasicView.include({
        init: function(viewInfo, params) {
            var self = this;
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var model = self.controllerParams.modelName in ['res.partner','product.template'] ? 'True' : 'False';
            if(model) {
                session.user_has_group('test_modulo.group_archive').then(function(has_group) {
                    if(!has_group) {
                        self.controllerParams.archiveEnabled = 'False' in viewInfo.fields;
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });
});
```

source : [Remove Archive and Unarchive options from menu 'Action' for users with no access rights](https://gist.github.com/goliveirab/a3dafb432338d7250d32e548151bfd9c)

Answer (score 0):

If you are version 15, call that javascript from manifest instead of using xml.

```
'assets': {
'web.assets_backend': [
'test_modulo/static/src/js/basic_view.js',
],
},
```